# Continuity/Bounded Lipschitz Continuity of a sample path of stochastic process and adaptedness

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, continuity, lipschitz-functions

A 3 part question.

Suppose $X:[0,1]\times\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded and progressively measurable (with respect to the filtration $\left\{\mathscr{F}_t\right\}_{t\in[0,1]}$) stochastic process.

Note that by bounded I mean:
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{(t,\omega)\in [0,1]\times\Omega}\left\vert X(t,\omega)\right\vert <\infty
\end{equation*}
Define the process $X_n:[0,1]\times\Omega$ by:
\begin{equation*}
X_n(t,\omega):= n\int_{0\vee t-\tfrac{1}{n}}^t X(s,\omega) ds
\end{equation*}
Then is:

1) $X_n$ continuous in $t$ (I know this is true but can't show it...I've been stuck on it for a long while now).

2) If 1. is true, then is $X_n$ is Lipschitz Continuous in $t$? (I originally tried to prove this statement, but got horribly stuck so I thought I would try to prove a weaker statement first....which I still couldn't prove unfortunately.

3) Show that $X_n$ is adapted with respect to the filtration $\left\{\mathscr{F}_t\right\}_{t\in[0,1]}$

Many thanks.

Comment: 1) follows from 2) which follows from $|X_n(t) - X_n(s)|\le |t-s| \sup X$ (prove this). 3) follows from the progressive measurability (this is more tricky, and you have to assume the completeness of filtration).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there any chance you could show me how to do 2)? This is exactly where I get stuck (showing that $\left\vert X_n(t) - X_s(t)\right\vert \le |t-s|\sup X$. I can show it for the case when s = 0, which is easy....but I cannot show it when s>0!

Comment: In fact, $2$ is missing from the rhs. Anyway,  try this: $|X_n(t) - X_n(s) |\le \int_{A} |X(u) |du\le \dots$

Comment: Could you please give me a hint on what you would choose the set $A$ to be?

Comment: Something like $[s,t]\cup[s-1/n,t-1/n]$

Comment: Ah thank you for that hint. I got it now. With regards to tackling adaptedness, how would you suggest I start (assuming that we have completeness), or is there a resource you could point me towards which would show me how to prove this?

Comment: Hint: if $F(x,y)$ is jointly measurable, then $I(x) = \int F(x,y) dy$ is measurable.